# When configuring an EAR project in Maven is it required that my WAR and EJB also be separate projects?

Tags: java, maven, war, ear

This requires that for every "one application", I have to setup numerous projects in Eclipse. I don't want this. Logically our source, libraries, configuration, etc., are for a single application, and it gets deployed as a single EAR, so having a POM inheritance and folder hierarchy is cumbersome to maintain. However, the tutorials I see for setting up an EAR project all show it broken out into numerous modules. Is it possible to circumvent this approach?

Answer (score 5):

I would say it is a best practice to keep the EJB and WAR and EAR separate. This way you can maintain the dependencies of each "module" separately. And if you ever wish to package your EJB into more than one EAR, it is easier to do so this way. You can use an overarching "project POM" that takes care of invoking the module POM's and getting your jars, wars, and ears created.

Sometimes the more "cumbersome" activities help with being more disciplined and solve issues that creep up later.

Comment: "And if you ever wish to package your EJB into more than one EAR, it is easier to do so this way." And if we don't? If I have one EAR, one WAR, and my EJBs will all live in this one WAR, then why would I want separate modules? I understand why Maven uses this module concept, but it seems to me that this "flexibility" now forces you to be flexible only in a way that Maven can understand.

Comment: We use the IBM extended versions of Eclipse (ie, Rational Application Developer, etc.) here at our shop. And even if you skip Maven, the IDE wizards set up a project structure that separates EJBs, WARs, and EARs. If you think about this, it makes sense. It separates the responsibilities of each area so only the configuration files/code related to the purpose of each artifact is necessary. It keeps from clutter. I wouldn't say you'll never separate your projects into another EAR. Over time as your app grows, you may find you may do just that..... :)

Answer (score 2):

My first comment would be if you aren't adding `.rar` files to your EAR than you might be happier putting your EJBs and libraries right into your `.war` file and skipping the EAR.

For many years you were forced to keep EJBs and Servlets separate and this necessitated EAR files if you wanted to use both.  In Java EE 6, we added the "EJBs in .wars" feature which is as simple as it sounds; it allows for EJB to be inside the `WEB-INF/classes/` or `WEB-INF/lib/` directories.

In Java EE 6, WARs are the new EARs.

You can of, course split, things up into ***Maven modules*** and would recommend you do that according to your own needs.  In terms of ***JavaEE modules*** it sounds like you just need the one war file.